# Prolog - Facts to rules

Tags: prolog

This question is related to this one : [Prolog - Reduce the knowledge base by deduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49864583/prolog-reduce-the-knowledge-base-by-deduction)

I've removed all the fact and rules that can deducted but I now have to write new facts which have been deducted.

As an example : 
        `conclusion_premise( is_a( X, thing), is_a( X, house ) )`

will become : `is_a( X, thing) :- is_a( X, house).`

In a way I need to split the rule `conclusion_premise(A,B)` but how can I get `A = is_a(X, thing)` and `B = is_a(X, house)`.

Thanks again.

**EDITED**

So far I have this to clean up the database :

```
clean_database:-
    findall( Conclusion, ( conclusion_premise( Conclusion, Premise ), Premise ), L ),
    list_to_set( L, L_no_duplicate),
    removeFactcs(L_no_duplicate),
    conclusion_premise(A,B), B, retract(conclusion_premise(A,B)).
    % need somehow to add the rule that have been deducted.

removeFactcs([]).
removeFactcs([X|XS]) :-
    retract(X),
    removeFactcs(XS).
```

Comment: @GuyCoder Thanks for your reply. I'm aware of the `=..` and it's use like this example `?- foo(hello, X) =.. List.
List = [foo, hello, X] ` but I can't get it to work.

Comment: @GuyCoder Yes that is exactly what I'm trying to do.